# Creating an Explicit Index column out of an Index in SQLite

Tags: indexing, sqlite

I have a very big SQLite3 database that looks like this:

[image]

I created an Index out of the 4 columns displayed above:
 QUOTE_DATE, EXPIRATION, STRIKE, OPTION_TYPE.
To do so, I ran `CREATE INDEX DEST_INDEX ON DATA(QUOTE_DATE,EXPIRATION,STRIKE,OPTION_TYPE);`.

I was under the impression that the index would be added as a new column in my table. And that I would be able to loop through my database using this index in a for loop. I was wrong.

**Problem:**
I want to be able to loop through my database (outside SQL, in Matlab, for example) by making queries like `SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE INDEX=i`. But the index that I created is not explicitly available.

**Question:**
Is it possible to create an explicit index as a column that mimics the one I created with `CREATE INDEX`?

Is it possible to make queries using the index, but without using `WHERE` for each different column? Is there a better solution?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What did you think this new column would look like? And in your example of `SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE INDEX = i`, what would `i` look like? I don't think "index" means what you think it means, so it may help if you explain more about exactly what you want to ask the database, and what you expect the results of your query to be. (An "index", in database terms, is a device that can speed up lookups on particular keys in the database; it won't be available as a visible column.)

Comment: Hey @MattGibson , thanks for helping! I think it is easier to explain with 1 column, and extend from there. Say the first 10 rows of this column have the same value, then the index would be 1. And then the next row has some other value, and it repeats for 4 rows, then the index would be 2. And the next row has some other value, and it repeats for 23 rows, then the index would be 3, and so on. The same idea for 4 columns, but whenever one of the columns change, the index would change.

Comment: @MattGibson it would be like doing `SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE COL1=1stvalForCol1, COL2=1stvalForCol2, COL3=1stvalForCol3, COL4=1stvalForCol4`, getting this query back, doing whatever I need to do, and then moving on to `SELECT * FROM DATA WHERE COL1=2ndvalForCol1, COL2=1stvalForCol2, COL3=1stvalForCol3, COL4=1stvalForCol4`, and so on. But instead of having to know all possible values for each column (which would take a long time to find out, because the database is quite big), I could just do `WHERE INDEX=i` and change `i`.

Comment: Assuming the table gets modified and extended by a column like you wanted (lets call it "myindex"), I think that is not so hard (though not as easy as one line of "create index...". Do you need to be able to add more entries to the database? What do you want to happen, if and when that happens? Is it OK to do the same method for making "myindex" (whatever that method is)? Or do you need some mechanism to automatically update "myindex" when new rows are entered. Keep in mind that the old way of inserting is probably not useable without change, it would need to somehow serve the new column.

Comment: Could you provide a suitably tailored toy database, which can be used to try and verify any proposed solution? Some lines of `create table ...;` and several lines of `insert ...;` or maybe just a `.dump`. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Yunnosch hey there! I won't need to add more entries to the database, the number of rows is fixed. And the new column `myindex` will only use those 4 columns I mentioned, i.e., I won't be adding any other columns. So, pretty much the database is what it currently is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fact that you will not have to extend/update the new table, you can simply skip doing a trigger and do not have to worry about changing whatever inserts the data.

So you can just create a new version of your table, "idata".
Then check the result and, if you like it, drop the old table and rename the new one.
(I do not provide code for that, because I do not want to be the author of the code which killed your database.;-) It seems ancient and is probably not easy to replace.)

I made my own MCVE for your problem, it is at the end of the answer.
Please consider providing one for your next SQLite question.

Note:
You might want to only use the table "idxdata". It consists of only the non-redundant entries in "data". That would save a lot of space, especially if "data" is really as big as you say.
In that case you should remove the "temporary" keyword. And not use the code from `create table idata` at all.

```
create temporary table idxdata
( QUOTE_DATE date, 
  EXPIRATION date, 
  STRIKE int, 
  OPTION_TYPE CHAR(1), 
  idx integer primary key
);

insert into idxdata 
  select distinct
    QUOTE_DATE,
    EXPIRATION,
    STRIKE,
    OPTION_TYPE,
    NULL
  from data;
```

Content of "idxdata":

```
2012-01-03|2012-01-06|1000|C|1
2012-01-04|2012-01-07|1000|C|2
2012-01-04|2012-01-07|1000|B|3
2012-02-04|2012-02-07|1000|B|4
```

More code for extending data to idata, with additional idx column):

```
create table idata
( QUOTE_DATE date,
  EXPIRATION date,
  STRIKE int,
  OPTION_TYPE CHAR(1),
  idx integer);

insert into idata
  select *
  from data
  join idxdata
  using (QUOTE_DATE, EXPIRATION, STRIKE, OPTION_TYPE);

select * from idata;
```

OUTPUT:

```
QUOTE_DATE  EXPIRATION  STRIKE      OPTION_TYPE  idx
----------  ----------  ----------  -----------  ----------
2012-01-03  2012-01-06  1000        C            1
2012-01-03  2012-01-06  1000        C            1
2012-01-03  2012-01-06  1000        C            1
2012-01-03  2012-01-06  1000        C            1
2012-01-04  2012-01-07  1000        C            2
2012-01-04  2012-01-07  1000        C            2
2012-01-04  2012-01-07  1000        C            2
2012-01-04  2012-01-07  1000        B            3
2012-01-04  2012-01-07  1000        B            3
2012-02-04  2012-02-07  1000        B            4
2012-02-04  2012-02-07  1000        B            4
2012-02-04  2012-02-07  1000        B            4
```

MCVE foundation:

```
CREATE TABLE data(QUOTE_DATE date, EXPIRATION date, STRIKE int, OPTION_TYPE CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO data(QUOTE_DATE,EXPIRATION,STRIKE,OPTION_TYPE) VALUES('2012-01-03','2012-01-06',1000,'C');
INSERT INTO data(QUOTE_DATE,EXPIRATION,STRIKE,OPTION_TYPE) VALUES('2012-01-03','2012-01-06',1000,'C');
INSERT INTO data(QUOTE_DATE,EXPIRATION,STRIKE,OPTION_TYPE) VALUES('2012-01-03','2012-01-06',1000,'C');
INSERT INTO data(QUOTE_DATE,EXPIRATION,STRIKE,OPTION_TYPE) VALUES('2012-01-03','2012-01-06',1000,'C');
INSERT INTO data(QUOTE_DATE,EXPIRATION,STRIKE,OPTION_TYPE) VALUES('2012-01-04','2012-01-07',1000,'C');
INSERT INTO data(QUOTE_DATE,EXPIRATION,STRIKE,OPTION_TYPE) VALUES('2012-01-04','2012-01-07',1000,'C');
INSERT INTO data(QUOTE_DATE,EXPIRATION,STRIKE,OPTION_TYPE) VALUES('2012-01-04','2012-01-07',1000,'C');
INSERT INTO data(QUOTE_DATE,EXPIRATION,STRIKE,OPTION_TYPE) VALUES('2012-01-04','2012-01-07',1000,'B');
INSERT INTO data(QUOTE_DATE,EXPIRATION,STRIKE,OPTION_TYPE) VALUES('2012-01-04','2012-01-07',1000,'B');
INSERT INTO data(QUOTE_DATE,EXPIRATION,STRIKE,OPTION_TYPE) VALUES('2012-02-04','2012-02-07',1000,'B');
INSERT INTO data(QUOTE_DATE,EXPIRATION,STRIKE,OPTION_TYPE) VALUES('2012-02-04','2012-02-07',1000,'B');
INSERT INTO data(QUOTE_DATE,EXPIRATION,STRIKE,OPTION_TYPE) VALUES('2012-02-04','2012-02-07',1000,'B');
```

Using: SQLite 3.18.0 2017-03-28

Comment: Wow! Wow! I really appreciate your answer, thank you so much for your help and for your effort in solving this! I was just trying it out and understanding what you were doing, and it does exactly what I wanted. The table `idata` is what I want because there are other columns that contain variables that are important and that vary each row, but did not need to be added to the index idx. I will be more careful about the `MCVE` next time, thanks! :D